# Summarise but keep length variable (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Basic dplyr question... Respondents could select multiple companies that they use. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- tibble(
 CompanyA = rep(c(0:1),5),
 CompanyB = rep(c(1),10),
 CompanyC = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1)
)
test
```

If it were a forced-choice question - i.e., respondents could make only one selection - I would do the following for a basic summary table:

```
test %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(Response, n) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate("%" = round(100*n/sum(n)))
```

Note, however, that the "%" column is not what I want. I'm instead looking for *the proportion of total respondents for each individual response option* (since they could make multiple selections).

I've tried adding `mutate(totalrows = nrow(.)) %>%` prior to the `summarise_all` command. This would allow me to use that variable as the denominator in a later `mutate` command. However, `summarise_all` eliminates the "totalrows" var.

Also, if there's a better way to do this, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but couldn't you just take the mean of each column to get the proportion of total respondents for each individual response option? What I mean is if 3 out of 5 people choose Company A, then you data might look like `c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)`. If you take the mean, that's 0.6, which is the proportion of respondents who chose that option.

Comment: That totally works - was overthinking it. Please switch to answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you did want to continue to overthink it, you could change the `sum(n)` to `nrow(test)`, so the code would be `test %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(Response, n) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate("%" = round(100*n/nrow(test)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the proportion of respondents who chose an option when that variable is binary, you can take the mean. To do this with your test data, you can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(test, mean)
CompanyA CompanyB CompanyC 
     0.5      1.0      0.8
```

If you wanted to do this in a more complicated fashion (say your data is not binary encoded, but is stored as `1` and `2` instead), you could do that with the following:

```
test %>% 
    gather(key='Company') %>% 
    group_by(Company) %>% 
    summarise(proportion = sum(value == 1) / n())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Company  proportion
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 CompanyA        0.5
2 CompanyB        1  
3 CompanyC        0.8
```

Comment: I didn't know that about vars coded as 1 or 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you put all functions in a list within summarise, then this will work. You'll need to do some quick tidying up after though.

```
test %>% 
  summarise_all(
    list(
      rows = length,
      n = function(x){sum(x, na.rm = T)},
      perc = function(x){sum(x,na.rm = T)/length(x)}
    )) %>%
  tidyr::gather(Response, n) %>%
  tidyr::separate(Response, c("Company", "Metric"), '_') %>%
  tidyr::spread(Metric, n)
```

And you'll get this

```
  Company      n  perc  rows
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 CompanyA     5   0.5    10
2 CompanyB    10   1      10
3 CompanyC     8   0.8    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `tidyr::gather`:

```
test %>% 
  gather(Company, response) %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  summarise(`%` = 100 * sum(response) / n())
```